# InsertOoxml() method of content control is not working for web version of word document

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office365api

InsertOoxml() method of contentControl word office js api is not working in online Web version . Tried to get the ooxml of a sample chart from desktop and tried to run the same valid ooxml in web version using insertOoxml() and its throwing RichApi error . Attaching the json of web version script lab error

`{

"name": "RichApi.Error",

"code": "GeneralException",

"traceMessages": [],

"innerError": null,

"debugInfo": {

"code": "GeneralException",

"message": "unknown",

"errorLocation": "Body.insertOoxml",

"statement": "var insertOoxml = body.insertOoxml(...);",

"surroundingStatements": ["var root = context.root;", "var body = root.body;", "// Instantiate {body}", "// >>>>>", "var insertOoxml = body.insertOoxml(...);", "// <<<<<", "// Instantiate {insertOoxml}"],

"fullStatements": ["Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."]

},

"httpStatusCode": 500

}
`
Is the office.js word Api down ? because the same method was working last week.

InsertOoxml() method not working in web version of word

Comment: Have you met the General exception with the message "ooxmlmalformated"?If you have, this is a recent regression issue; we have just fixed it. The fix is rolling out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue in time. Sorry for the inconvenience caused to you. These two days we are actively working on this. The fix should be available to all of you. Please double check it in your environment after clearing your browser cache.
Please let us know if you have any further questions. Thank you all again!

Comment: Hi,
insertOoxml() method is working but the changes in the document are reflecting after some time (average time of around 10 to 15 secs).

Please try the sample code from the documentation : https://gist.github.com/src107/92c6ea11eb98062c8b91d5b858d941ac
Session Id: 24326398-95ab-48b6-a4e1-cdcc091c4550

Comment: Great to know! Thanks for your response! 
For the new issue you mention this time, we have already created an internal work item<7776847> on it. We will keep track of this issue and let you know if there are any updates.